# Xpath for scrapy with atom namespace

Tags: xpath, scrapy, namespaces

I am trying to scrape data from an xml file using scrapy. 
The file is structures as follows:

```
<feed xml:base="https://example.com/sap/...">
<entry><id>http://example.com/.../idset</id>
<m:properties>
<d:SubID>xyz</d:JobID>
<d:Posting>123456</d:Posting>
<d:Title>BoringTitle</d:Title>
</m:properties>
</entry>
</feed>
```

In Scrapy I import the atom namespace:

```
xxs = XmlXPathSelector(response)
xxs.register_namespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
```

And it is possible to extract some of the data with

```
xxs.xpath("//atom:entry").extract()
```

However, I found it impossible to select the data with a colon:

```
<d:Title>BoringTitle</d:Title>
```

What would be the right xpath to print the title?
Maybe there is a simple answer, I am a mechanical engineer doing this for a hobby project.

Any help would be appreciated!

Kind regards

John

Comment: You need to define a namespace for the namespace prefix `d`, too.

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned in the question comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54047092/xpath-for-scrapy-with-atom-namespace#comment94931290_54047092), you need to add a namespace for `d` as well.

However, in your case, it may be better to simply [remove all namespaces](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#removing-namespaces) and work without them.